# QTableWidget cells values not appearing in QGIS

Tags: qtablewidget, qgis, qtablewidgetitem

I want to use a QTableWidget inside a QGIS plugin in order to show to the user the items of the following lists: 
   [QTableWidget: tableDomestic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybQEr.jpg)

```
    xnames = ["BOD", "TN", "TP"]
    cat1 = [60, 12, 2.5]
    cat2 = [36, 10.8, 2.4]
    cat3 = [6, 2.4, 2.4]
    cat4 = [3, 2.4, 0.5]
```

This is the code I am using and the tableDomestic appears when plugin is running but the cells are empty. I thought that maybe I need a statement that will make cells values appear but so far by reading other examples I do not find sthing. I am very new to programming and I would appreciate your help and guidances.

```
     # populate the field table header
    listHeaders = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    self.dlg.tableDomestic.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(listHeaders)
    self.dlg.tableDomestic.setVerticalHeaderLabels(xnames)
```

Normally, the following should be in a loop but just to check that everything is working I set i=0

```
    # first column: populate factors for 1st category (cat1)
    BODfactors = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(cat1[0])
    self.dlg.tableDomestic.setItem(0, 0, BODfactors)

        # second column: populate factors for 2nd category (cat2)
    TNfactors = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(cat2[0])
    self.dlg.tableDomestic.setItem(0, 1, TNfactors)

        # third column: populate factors for 3rd category (cat3)
    TPfactors = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(cat3[0])
    self.dlg.tableDomestic.setItem(0, 2, TPfactors)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it!!

items inside cells of QTableWidget should be strings!!
    cat1 = ['60', '12', '2.5']
    cat2 = ['36', '10.8', '2.4']
    cat3 = ['6', '2.4', '2.4']
    cat4 = ['3', '2.4', '0.5']